# Needing to replace a heater

Tags: walls, mounting, installation

Hello I have a obsolete gas heater in my bathroom, however I need heat in my living room how can I get the line from bathroom to living room? Hence it is only about a foot or two from where a heater is already in bathroom but that heater is too old ceramic. Please help we cannot afford another winter with spot heaters on our electric bill and we freeze.

Comment: Can you use a fan. If you are afraid of shock you could have the fan blow into the bathroom  which will also force heat out. I would suggest you get a larger heater installed in your living room and properly vented. That would be a lot less then a funeral because of CO poisoning. I would expect what you save on the electricity will pay the bill in maybe two years.

Comment: Is the old heater in bathroom still working ? are there doors between bathroom and living room? do you want the hot air from bathroom into living room.

Comment: Are you asking about getting the gas pipe extended from the bathroom to the living room?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the heater in the bathroom the only heat in the place? How is it vented (burning gas tends to produce vapors that, if not properly vented, can be toxic)? What kind of gas are you burning? Please provide a picture of the bathroom heater and the piping to it. Do you own or rent the place? Is there a basement, crawl space or attic to run additional piping through? We need a _lot_ more detail than you've provided in order to help answer your question...